# Is there a smarter way to input a series of names in a function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

im fairly new to R and programming as a whole.
I am working with a ton of plots and need to visualize them on 8x12 combined plot which works fine, using the following command:

```
ggarrange(plot_1, plot_2, plot_3, plot_4, plot_5, plot_6, plot_7, plot_8, plot_9, plot_10, plot_11, plot_12, 
              plot_13, plot_14, plot_15, plot_16, plot_17, plot_18, plot_19, plot_20, plot_21, plot_22, plot_23, plot_24, 
              plot_25, plot_26, plot_27, plot_28, plot_29, plot_30, plot_31, plot_32, plot_33, plot_34, plot_35, plot_36, 
              plot_37, plot_38, plot_39, plot_40, plot_41, plot_42, plot_43, plot_44, plot_45, plot_46, plot_47, plot_48, 
              plot_49, plot_50, plot_51, plot_52, plot_53, plot_54, plot_55, plot_56, plot_57, plot_58, plot_59, plot_60, 
              plot_61, plot_62, plot_63, plot_64, plot_65, plot_66, plot_67, plot_68, plot_69, plot_70, plot_71, plot_72, 
              plot_73, plot_74, plot_75, plot_76, plot_77, plot_78, plot_79, plot_80, plot_81, plot_82, plot_83, plot_84, 
              plot_85, plot_86, plot_87, plot_88, plot_89, plot_90, plot_91, plot_92, plot_93, plot_94, plot_95, plot_96,
              ncol = 12, nrow = 8)
```

There must be an easier way where i dont have to write every plot individually?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

```
do.call(ggarange, c(mget(ls(pattern = '^plot_[0-9]+$')),nrow = 12, ncol = 8))
```

Comment: That works thanks! However the order of plots is different, is there any way to solve this? :)

Comment: @Salt_Industry sure, just use `mget(str_sort(ls(pattern = '^plot_[0-9]+$'), numeric = TRUE))`